# How to encrypt a *.mdf file with a password with LocalDb?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012-express, localdb

I have a `.mdf` database file created with Visual Studio 2012 using Entity Framework.

I tried to secure my database with a password but I don't find a way to do that, please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Databases are typically secured by user accounts and passwords. If you need to protect the data at rest, consider block-level encryption products (e.g., Vormetric).

Comment: A SQL Server database (`.mdf`) cannot be *password protected* like a file-based system such as Access or something like that. You have to define access permissions on a per-user basis - you cannot globally define a password to lock/unlock the SQL Server database

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the long run?

Comment: Sql Compact database *.sdf can be password protected.